# How to dynamically add enctype="multipart/form-data" to form?

Tags: jquery, forms, multipartform-data

I have a form, in which users can submit either a textarea or an audio file, but not both.

**Form**

```
<form id="contact-form" action="/contact" method="post" >
  <input type="file" id="file-upload"  name="file" accept="audio/mp3" capture>
<div class="file_name"></div> 
 <input  name="title" value="">
 <textarea class="body" name="body"></textarea>
 <button type="submit" value="Submit"> Send</button>
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#file-upload').change(function() { 
    var file = $('#file-upload')[0].files[0].name;
    $('.file_name').text(file);
    $( ".body" ).slideToggle( "slow");
  });
```

I'm wondering how can I append `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the form in case a file is added to form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check .attr docs

[.attr() Jquery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2)